# Graph Node doesnt loop through all neighbouring nodes?

Tags: java, recursion, graph

Im having troubles with a Graph assignment, i've run into an issue i cant seem to find.

```
System.out.println(plattegrond.getGraph().neighbours("Een").toString());
System.out.println(plattegrond.isRoute("Een", "Drie", new HashSet<String>()));
```

These lines of code print

```
[Twee, Drie, Vier]
false
```

So it seems, that "Een" has "Twee", "Drie", and "Vier" as neighbours.
However the isRoute method returns false. the method is shown below.

```
public boolean isRoute(String nodeA, String nodeB, Set<String> visited) {

        visited.add(nodeA);

        if(nodeA.equals(nodeB)) {
            return true;
        }

        for(String neighbour : graph.neighbours(nodeA)) {
            if(!visited.contains(neighbour)) {
                return isRoute(neighbour, nodeB, visited);
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
```

I've traced all steps with the debugger, and in the enhanced for loop, "Drie" will not come up as a neighbour. "Twee" and "Four" however will. The same problem happens if i try to find a path to "Zes". When i ask "Twee" what its neighbours are, it will say

```
[Een, Vier, Zes]
```

the isRoute method will again return false when i ask it to find a route to "Zes". Again 
"Zes" does not come up in the loop as neighbour.
However, when i ask it to find a route to either "Twee" or "Four" it will return true.

Im completely lost on this one.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with your neighbours(node) method then!!

Comment: The neighbours(node) method is supplied to me (as is the graph) and i dont have the source for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem there... In your for you have IF statement with a return.. First Neighbour is Twee and it is not in the list so it will visit Twee and never go back to the next iteration because of that return statement.

Try using a boolean variable and doing something like this:

```
boolean b = false;

for(String neighbour : graph.neighbours(nodeA)) {
        if(!visited.contains(neighbour)) {
           // this statement can never change b to false once it becomes true
           // and you make sure you return after checking your whole set of neighbours
            b = b || isRoute(neighbour, nodeB, visited);
        }
    }

return b;
```

This might not be the exact correct solution but at least now you know where is your problem... You are returning after first item and not iterating over all the neighbours.

Comment: Okay, this trick did the job, however i dont quite understand why.
you put the value b into b again OR call the isRoute() method?

Comment: It is not a trick... try the following: for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { System.out.println(i); return; } You are printing 0 and returing right after, won't print the rest... It is the same thing there

Comment: Here is the logic: You start by saying that there is no route(false)... false OR true = true. false OR = false. If you ever return true from one of the calls it means you arrived in the node you wanted (there is some path to it) and then you must change it to true

Comment: Aah i see, adding () instantly made it apparent to me :) thanks alot

b = (b || isRoute(neighbour, nodeB, visited))